# MySQL design problem

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to normalize my database but I'm having a headache getting to grips with it. I am developing a CMS where Facebook users can create a page on my site. So far this is what I have

```
page
----
uid            - PK AI
slug           - Slug URL
title          - Page title
description    - Page description
image          - Page image
imageThumbnail - Thumbnail of image
owner          - The ID of the user that created the page
views          - Page views
timestamp      - Date page was created

user
----
uid  - PK AI
fbid - Facebook ID
(at a later date may add profile options i.e name, website etc)

tags
----
uid - PK AI
tag - String (tag name)

page_tag
--------
pid - Page id (uid from page table)
tid - Tag id (uid from tag table)

page_user
---------
pid - Page id (uid form page table)
uid - User ID (uid from user table)
```

I've tried to seperate as much information as needed without going over the top. I created a seperate table for tags because I don't want tag names being repeated. If the database holds 100,000+ pages, the repeated tags will add to storage and speed no doubt.

Is there any problems with the design? Or anything I'm doing wrong? I remember learning this at university but I've done very little database design since then.

I'd rather get it right the first time then have the headache later on.

Comment: I would have use `pid` for the PK of `page` and `tid` for the PK of `tag` to help me write JOINs without headaches. But all the rest looks pretty fine.

Comment: I'd also name the table `tag` and not `tags` so all table names use singular form.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me.  How bad can it be with five tables?

You have users, pages, and tags.  Users can have many pages; pages can be referred to by many users.  A page can have many tags; a tag can be associated with many pages.

Sums it up for me.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Your next concern is indexes.  You'll want an index for every WHERE clause that you'll use to query.